# Is it possible to make audio tag unclickable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to make an `audio` tag unclickable. I tried with `.off()` and `.css("pointer-events", "none")` but it didn't work. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Removing `controls` is not an option, I assume? `pointer-events: none;` works in Firefox Nightly 84.0a1. Since these media elements are implemented with shadow DOMs, their event behavior may be a bit weird, yes, so making own audio controls rather than having the default ones enabled may be the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pointer-events seems to work perfectly fine. Perhaps you were using incorrect syntax?

```js
$("audio").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls></audio>
```

Comment: Realized it now, it really was a syntax error. Lack of attention from me. Thanks!